# Direction furthest away from a set points

Tags: geometry

Say a number of points are arrayed on the edge of a circle. Starting from the centre of the circle, how do I find what direction I should move in to maximize my distance from the red closest point? I want to *get away* from the points in red. Another way of framing the question is to find a new point on the circle that maximizes the distance from it the nearest red point. Below are some examples, with my desired directions in blue, and points I want to get away from in red.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are those points represented? As x/y coordinates, or degrees on the circle? Do you know the centre of the circle?

Comment: "maximize my distance from the closest point" I think this constraint requires a bit of clarification.

Comment: @tobias_k The points on the circle edge can be represented as either x/y or as degrees. I do have the position of the circle center.

Comment: @Reblochon Masque yes, I should clarify that I want to find another point (or direction) on the circle that is the furthest possible distance from the closest red point. I want to _get away_ from the red points. Hope that helps.

Comment: Noted, thank you! In that case, @HugoRune approach is correct and you should consider accepting his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sort all points on the circle into a list, clockwise
- pair each point with its successor, and the last point with the first one
- find the pair with the greatest angular distance (ca. 200° clockwise between the 2nd and 3th point in the first pic)

The desired direction is halfway between those two points ( ca. 100° after the 2nd point in the first pic)